# Update React State dependent from another state with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update a state dependent on another state change. For example I have state one and if state one changes I want to change state two dependent on the changes of state one. What is the best way of doing this? I have prepared two examples.

**Example 1**

Here I change State2 inside the state change callback of state 1.

```js
const DependentStateExample1 = () => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(0);
  const [state2, setState2] = useState(0);

  const changeState1 = () => {
    setState1((prev) => {
      const newState = prev + 5;
      setState2((prevState2) => prevState2 + newState);
      return newState;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{state1}</span><span>{state2}</span>
      <button onClick={changeState1}>Change State 1</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Example 2**

Here I use useEffect, which will execute everytime when state1 changes.

```js
const DependentStateExample2 = () => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(0);
  const [state2, setState2] = useState(0);

  const changeState1 = () => {
    setState1((prev) => prev + 5);
  };

  useEffect(() => setState2((prev) => prev + state1), [state1]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{state1}</span>
      <span>{state2}</span>
      <button onClick={changeState1}>Change State 1</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Both ways give me the same result, but which one is better, or is there a better way solving this? Can someone please explain?

Comment: Is there any particular requirement to use 2 different states? Why can't use in a single state?

Comment: No, there is no particular reason for using 2 different states. To use a single state is actually a good idea, then I can use useReducer instead of useState. But anyway, is it still possible to do it with 1 state each?

Comment: Any news on that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the fact that YOU know the relation between the first state and the second, so instead of writing this logical dependency in code, you could take it out and just write the code so that it produces the same result, but so that React doesn't have to 'wait' until setState has completed:

```
setState1(oldState1 => oldState1 + 5);
setState2(oldState2 => oldState1 + oldState2 + 5); // we know setState is async so remember on the second line you don't have yet setState1 completed
```

The principle could be extended for more complex dependencies between the states.